# Bash script to find && mkdir

Tags: linux, bash, centos

**Scenario**

I'm switching IMAP client on a mail server for several thousands domains with following structure :

Mail folder location: `/home/mail/domains` (just an example)

Maildir for *domain1.com* contains following folders: (again just an example)

```
.Sent.2002.May
.Sent.2002.June
.Personal.Home.Jack
```

Maildir for *domain2.com* contains

```
.Sent.2008.June
.Emails.Test.test2
```

Maildir for *domain3.com* contains

```
.Sent.2012.Files
.Archive.2014.May
```

**Problem:**

My new IMAP client throws an error whenever intermediate folder is not there. Example for *domain1.com*:

If `.Sent.2002` folder doesn exist it will throw an error when I try to view `.Sent.2002.May`

**Task**

I need a script to:

1. Find folders in `/home/mail/domains/$domain/Maildir/` with this naming pattern `.$1.$2.$3`
2. Create intermediate folders `/home/mail/domains/$domain/.$1.$2/`
3. Chown `/home/mail/domains/$domain/.$1.$2/` to user `mail`

Tried it manually for one domain and the IMAP client error is gone.

Need help with the script. I'm not sure how to translate arguments from find to mkdir in this case, because folder names always vary.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with the script. Did you have a question?

Comment: Hmm, yes I need to create that bash script for the outlined task. My question is how? I'm not sure how to translate arguments from `find` to `mkdir` in this case, because folder names always vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
for i in `find  /home/mail/domains/$domain/Maildir/  -exec basename {} \; ` 
    do
    DIR=`echo $i |  awk -F. '{print "/home/mail/domains/$domain/." $2 "." $3}'` 
    mkdir $DIR
    chown mail $DIR
done
```

Executing it here, I got:

```
mkdir /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Personal.Home
chown mail /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Personal.Home
mkdir /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Sent.2002
chown mail /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Sent.2002
mkdir /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Sent.2002
chown mail /home/mail/domains/$domain/.Sent.2002
```